# How do I rotate an index in sphinx that removes deleted records as well as adding new ones?

Tags: indexing, sphinx

Right now I simply run

```
indexer --config /home/indexer/sphinx.conf.php --rotate idx_TableName
```

However it seems to me it is adding new records but deleted records are still found by searchD. Is there a way to have the Indexer add new records only and remove old records?

Answer (score 0):

That command completely regenetates the index. A complete new index is generated, and the old one simple deleted. Nothing is persisted between them.

If you are still seeing old records either its something wrong with the sql_query, that you still index deleted records, or maybe you are searching other indexes as well, which still contain old data.

A 'standard' way of managing updates is to use so called delta indexes http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/delta-updates.html

Or use Real-Time indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:   sudo indexer --rotate --all

This will simply update your indexes.